# Creating a directory tree at a hierarchical level

Tags: windows, command-line

I'm trying to create a directory tree for a specific set of folders at a certain level. I found how to limit the `Tree` results using Regular Expressions but I'm unsure as to how I can limit the resulting tree to only say, directories at the first level instead of it finding all sub-directories recursively.

In Linux it's possible to do `tree -L 1` to limit results to the first level. How can I do this in Windows cmd?

**Example** - If my folder directory is as follows:

```
Folder A
    Folder B
        Folder C
Folder D
    Folder E
```

I want my tree result to be:

```
--Folder A
----Folder B
--Folder D
----Folder E
```

(Only showing 2 levels)

The `Tree` help is as follows:

```
Graphically displays the folder structure of a drive or path.

TREE [drive:][path] [/F] [/A]

   /F   Display the names of the files in each folder.
   /A   Use ASCII instead of extended characters.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't without using some other tool. In an app in C# for instance this would be a few lines of code.

The batch file CDS.bat that [is here](http://www.chebucto.ns.ca/~ak621/DOS/Bat-Adv1.html) claims to do what you want. I haven't tested it.